# find data in Sql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stored data  separated by ,  for example

activities: 1,12,13
activities: 1,5,12
activities: 1,17,13

How to create query to select data where activities contains 13

Comment: [MySql string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: We love you and we're happy you're here. Please show us the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('13', activities) > 0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,now i'm tring to find 13,1 in activities

Comment: SELECT * 
from table 
where (FIND_IN_SET('13',`FK_ACTIVITES`) + FIND_IN_SET('1',`FK_ACTIVITES`))>0